# Verificar se existe nó no Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase

Boa tarde, estou verificando se existe um nó no Firebase, caso exista eu apenas irei incrementar o valor nesse nó, mas quando não existir eu irei criar o nó, porém o else não está funcionando. Se é a primeira vez que o usuário irá cadastrar uma despesa mensal, o nó mês/ano ainda não existirá, então preciso criá-lo, e nas próximas vezes o nó já estará criado, então eu só incremento com  o valor que já estiver cadastrado.

```
public void atualizarDespesaMensal(Double despesaMes, Double valorDigitado,String mesAno){

        //Recuperamos o email do usuario logado
        String emailUsuario = autenticacao.getCurrentUser().getEmail();
        //codificamos usando a classe Base64Custom
        String idUsuario = Base64Custom.codificarBase64(emailUsuario);

        movimentacaoSaldoMensalRef = firebaseRef.child("saldoMensal")
                .child(idUsuario);                    

        valueEventListenerAtualizarDespesaMensal = movimentacaoSaldoMensalRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot snapshot) {
              

                if (snapshot.child(mesAno).exists()) {
                    Log.i("IF", "O nó existe, vamos incrementa o valor"); //IF FUNCIONA
                    
                }else{
                    Log.i("ELSE", "Se o nó não existir irei criar"); //NO ELSE NÃO FUNCIONA
                }   

            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError error) {

            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

tente utilizar o increment do firebase.

```
movimentacaoSaldoMensalRef = firebaseRef.child("saldoMensal")
    .child(idUsuario)
    .set(firebase.database.ServerValue.increment(valor))
```

este método incrementa caso o nó já tenha um valor e cria caso não exista.
lembrar que este calculo é realizado no servidor. e não no cliente.